# How to add filter to category products(Show only with special price)

Tags: magento-1.8, price, filter

I'm new to magento(i'm using 1.8 btw), I currently have price and color filters on category page and they are working fine, but I can't find any help for adding a new filter to show only products that currently have a special price.

I don't want a specific page to show all "special price" products, I need this to be done with a filter, on the category page.

Comment: are you u want to show the special on left navigation>?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved the problem:

Probably not the best solution, but it's working...

On my product/list.phtml I check if I want to show the filter or not, then if yes:

> $todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

```
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();

$category->load(Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId());

$collection = $category->getProductCollection();

$collection
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('or'=> array(
        0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate),
        1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
), 'left')
->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(
        0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
        1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
), 'left')
->addAttributeToFilter(
        array(
                array('attribute' => 'special_from_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')),
                array('attribute' => 'special_to_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null'))
        )
)
->addAttributeToSort('special_from_date', 'asc')
->setVisibility(
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds()
);
```

$_productCollection = $collection;

Comment: I dont think that is the correct solution , as the collection in the list.phtml arrives already after the filtering/ordering process of the controller and block , so you are actually performing filtering/ordering on already filtered / ordered data . 
For example , if you have 500 items but only 9 are displayed per page , this code I think will only run on the 9 items of the specific page as determined by toolbar.php

Comment: Pagination will be broken by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Special price is also attribute like the color. You can enable it for filtering via admin - catalog - attributes - manage attributes - special price - show in layered navigation

Comment: This would work, but I would like to show only products that currently have a special price. Using it the way you said, it show all products with special price even if they don't have a special price anymore.
Is there a way to do this? Maybe changing some backend code?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But it is not very easy. You need to rewrite the apply method from the catalog/layer/filer/attribute, check the attribute code, and if it is the special price, add date-from / date-to limitation.

Comment: Would this work: (?)

$_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
if($isSpecialPrice){
 _productCollection
 ->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $dateToday))
 ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('date' => true, 'from' => $dateTomorrow));
}

Comment: You can try and share results with the community :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();

$category->load(Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId());

$collection = $category->getProductCollection();

$collection
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('or'=> array(
        0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate),
        1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
), 'left')
->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(
        0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
        1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
), 'left')
->addAttributeToFilter(
        array(
                array('attribute' => 'special_from_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null')),
                array('attribute' => 'special_to_date', 'is'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('not null'))
        )
)
->addAttributeToSort('special_from_date', 'asc')
->setVisibility(
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds()
);
```